# Making ImageView visible and invisibile

Tags: android

**My Xml file:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pagefw">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

**My activity class:-**

```
  int turn=1;
  iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     //iv1.setImageAlpha(0);
    iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
               "Image View 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(turn%2!=0)
                    {iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
                 else
                    {iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                    turn++;
        }
    });
```

**What I Did:-**
I added an ImageView in the activity having an image, which has onClickListener assigned to it.

**What I Want:-**
To my image set in the imageview to completely become invisible and visible after each click, i.e. after first click it becomes invisbile and after another click visible and so on.

**What I Get:-**
After first becoming invisible the image never becomes visible nor am I getting the toast when I click the invisible imageView. I also tried doing it with `iv1.setAlpha();` method but also with no result.

Comment: try with `iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);` instead of `iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Tried that getting same results. I thought View.GONE will also remove the space assigned to the imageView, I just want the image to become invisible.

Comment: see updated code which is working as u want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this , using this u'll not need any extra variable

```
if(iv1.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
   iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
   iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

**Edit:**

I have tried and worked using a Button or removing background.

You are applying click on same ImageView, thats the reason why not working for u.You should  apply onClick on a diff button. If want on same ImageView than u have to remove Background instead making it invisible.as ex, u have several method to remove bg/src which u can use.one of them

```
  iv1.setBackgroundResource(null);
```

**Edit-2**
Ur imageview must have a min height and width as after removing bg ,imageview clicking area is very small.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

and a boolean for handle image during onClick

```
  boolean avail=false;
```

and onClick code.

```
  if (avail) {
            iv1.setBackgroundResource(0);
            avail = false;
        } else {
            iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            avail = true;
        }
```

Comment: The best way to do what I want, but once it gets invisible it doesn't appear again.

Comment: Just did that, still the same results.

Comment: what u have tried ?.. share ur code. You have to use diff method for src/background. Or used using a diff?

Comment: I set the `iv1.setBackgroundResource(null);` just after initializing the imageView and the inside the `onClick()` I set `iv1.setBackgroundResource(null);` . So at starting the activity I am getting no image neither is there any change when I click the place where the imageView should be.

Comment: Now u don't have a need to making iv invisible/visible.

Comment: Will just have do so by using button because as @Abd said, you can't communicate with invisible imageview and originally that's what I was trying to do :(

Comment: I told u both alternative remove background or use onClick on diff button,yes u r saying the same.

Comment: I tries removing the background but still I was unable to communicate with the imageView, so atlast I thought I would have to try this some other way altogether. I think I will give it a try using `imageButton`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48799/discussion-between-manmohan-and-mohit)

Answer (score 1):

Make it more simple by using one `boolean` paramater that hold the `button` state, either pressed or not as following:

```
static final boolean isPressed= false;
iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
           "Image View 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(!isPressed){
           isPressed= true;
           iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            isPressed= false;
            iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah nice code. But is there something wrong with my code other than it being a bit tricky because of which I am not getting results?

Comment: Most probably there is something wrong with the if(condition) thats why I recommended a simpler way to handle the same state :) @Mohit

Comment: Still the same results :(

Comment: @Mohit, It`s important to know that when you make the `imageView` invisible, you will not be able to interaction with it again untill it is visible again :). To make sure of that Create `Button` and make it control the same logic for the `imageView` and you will see the result

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag on the image. Set tag 1 or 0 and check the tag to change the visibility of the image.

```
if(v.getTag()==0)
{
    iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    v.setTag() == 1;
}
else
{
    iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.setTag() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it this way:

in your xml you provide the actual width and height of a drawable and do not provide source:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="_some_value_"
     android:layout_height="_some_value_"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="140dp">
</ImageView>
```

That is for your view not to become of a size 0*0 when you set your background to something like null or transparent or whatever.

Then, in your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....

    iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);
    ...
}
```

And onClick():

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
           "Image View 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(turn%2!=0)
        {iv1.setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);}
    else
        {iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);}
    turn++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can simply it like this too:

```
iv1.setVisibility(!iv1.getVisibility());
```

Know what I mean?

```
if(iv1.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```